# List competitors for a given stock?

Tags: market-data

Where can I find a reasonably-priced or free API, database or CSV which contains a list of competitors for a given stock symbol?

For example, I want to find competitors for various symbols, like GOOG, TWTR, etc.

By reasonably priced, I mean, under $50 per month. I've seen Owler and others, but the pricing is hidden.

One option is to scrape data from Yahoo Finance, but I prefer to do it properly and leave that as a last resort. I tried to find an API that returns Yahoo Finance competitor data, but haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main classifications professionals use. You would need to purchase one of the two main standards, get it from your university or hand source it. Using this information it is easy to sort out which competitors are in a given sector.

The two main sources are the [Global Industry Classification Standard (GICS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Industry_Classification_Standard) and [Industry Classification Benchmark (ICB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Classification_Benchmark).

To obtain GICS: [click here](https://www.msci.com/gics)

To obtain ICB: [click here](http://www.icbenchmark.com/)

If you want to understand a companies key competitors analytically, without digging through the financials yourself. [Revere from FactSet](http://www.factset.com/campaigns/revere) sells supply chain data that may be useful.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. But the classification is too broad. For example, Microsoft's (MSFT) closest competitor is generally seen as AAPL. While IBM, RedHat also make (server) operating systems, I wouldn't say they are as closely linked as, say, GOOG and AAPL to MSFT. So the specifics matter a lot. Another example, Dominos Pizza (DPZ) and McDonalds are both fast foods. But McDonalds best competitor would more likely be Burger King.

Comment: @SilentSteel It is also important to note what you are asking is highly subjective, you might think MSFT and AAPL are the "closest competitors", I might think GOOG and MSFT,  AAPL and Samsung exc..

Comment: isn't there any open source table in github?

Answer (score 1):

[Barchart OnDemand's getCompetitors API](https://www.barchart.com/ondemand/api/getCompetitors) provides a list of related stock symbols (competitors) for an underlying stock input.